# Split several strings in a foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, split

I have these records:

```
Value  Part   Qty  
A      PartA  QtyA
B      PartB  QtyB
C      PartC  QtyC
```

I'm concatenating each column in different strings:

```
stringValue = A~B~C
stringPart = PartA~PartB~PartC
stringQty = QtyA~QtyB~QtyC
```

I want to split each string to get the original row value according to the position but I'm not sure how to do it any insight would be appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) the strings on '~'. Each array should match up on the same index unless your table has missing cells.

Comment: I have a feeling there may be a better solution to whatever overall problem you're trying to solve. Why are you taking the data and concatenating columns into strings, then splitting them into arrays again? Why not just populate lists instead? Do you do something else with the strings? What about using strongly typed objects to represent your data?

Comment: Hi @RufusL it is in that way because the values are on a form and I'm going to pass them to a task, that task is going to execute another logic to create job etc,

Comment: I don't see how that process prevents you from parsing the data into a list of objects that contain the related properties, like `class MyThing { public string Value { get; set; } public string Part { get; set; } public int Qty { get; set; } }` and `List<MyThing> thingsFromFormData` which you would then pass to the Task. At a minimum, you don't need to concatenate the columns into strings if you're just going to convert the data to something else later (unless you need the strings for something that you're not showing).

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] yourfirstrow = stringValue.Split(new string[] { "~" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

//yourfirstrow[0] first cell value
//yourfirstrow[1] second cell value
//yourfirstrow[2] third cell value
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be `yourFirstColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

Create some data storage

```
class Model
{
    string Value {get; set;}
    string Part {get; set;}
    string Quantity {get; set;}

}
```

Parse and format

```
private List<Model> _list = new List<Model>();

void MakeList()
{
    string[] values = "A~B~C".Split("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] parts = "PartA~PartB~PartC"("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] qtys = "QtyA~QtyB~QtyC"("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = new Model(){ Value = values[i], Part = parts[i], Quantity = qtys[i]};
        _list.Add(item);
    }

}

string[] GenerateCommaSeparatedRecords()
{
    return _list.Select(x => string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", x.Value, x.Part, x.Quantity)).ToArray();
}
```

You can generate any output you wish